# How to use whileloop in foreach loop?

Tags: php, html

**Question:**

I'm retrieving rows from a text area with a for each loop. 
But I can't use them in my while loop. The while loop only run once. I want it to run for all the rows in the text area. But it's only showing the description for the last B000number(B000575825).

How to fix this problem....?

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Select_description.php">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" rows="25" style="width: 150px;">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Data submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

$text = $_POST['text'];

$a = 0;
$b = 0;

foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $b000_number) {

    $a++;

    $query1 = "SELECT `description` FROM mat_index_items WHERE b000_number = '$b000_number'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $b++;
        $description= $row['description'];
        echo $description;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

echo "Foreach: ".$a;
echo "<br>";
echo "While: ".$b;
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: Have you checked the generated queries (use `var_dump($query1)`) and tested them outside of your application (using phpmyadmin or similar) to make sure that the queries looks correct and actually returns what you expect?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know it's vulnerable for SQL injection!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My query is working in phpmyadmin for all 3 B000 numbers

Comment: Does that mean that you _have_ dumped the queries and tried them separately or did you rewrite the queries in phpmyadmin? That's an important difference.  Do `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($query1); echo '</pre>';` to make sure you see any extra line breaks or spaces, which browsers usually don't show.

Comment: Just to make sure - use `trim($b000_number)` as there may be whitespace/new line etc.

Comment: @NigelRen Trim fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure there are no stray whitespace characters, use `trim()`...

```
$b000_number = trim($b000_number);
```